# Can I make a mutable collection of functions in Kotlin without them running?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, collections

In Python, I'm able to make a dictionary of function keywords and call their key without the other functions in the dictionary running. Is there a Kotlin equivalent?

I have created a mutableMapOf(1 to a(), 2 to b()), which partially works, but both functions run every time even if their key isn't called. In Python, I can say:

```py
def a(): print("Hi")
def b(): print("Bye")

function_dictionary = {1: a, 2: b} 
function_dictionary[1]() //runs a()
```

Whereas in Kotlin, I can only think of:

```
fun a(){println("Hi")}
fun b(){println("Bye")}

val functionMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Unit>(1 to a(), 2 to b()) //a() and b() both run 
functionMap[1] //runs a() again
```

In the Kotlin example, the functions run regardless of whether or not the map key they are assigned to has been selected. Can I make a map that works the same way as the dictionary does in Python?

Comment: "functionMap[1] //runs a() again" Are you sure about that? Your map is a map of Units, not functions. There's nothing to run again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you are invoking `a` and `b` while creating a map. You can pass references to the functions instead of invocation them. But you have to expicit invoke it later:

```
val functionMap = mutableMapOf(1 to ::a, 2 to ::b)
functionMap[1]!!() // prints Hi
```

also, you can wrap each function in the one more lambda:

```
val functionMap = mutableMapOf(1 to { a() }, 2 to { b() })
functionMap[1]!!() // prints Hi
```

Comment: And to add to that, the type of the dictionary should be mutableMap<Int, () -> Unit> instead of mutableMap<Int, Unit>. One expects a function returning Unit and the other expects the value of Unit.